# Use of would have

Tags: would-have-been

After a near miss from getting hit by a ball saying which of the following is grammatically accurate
"What would have you done if it hit my eye?" Or "What would you have done if it hit my eye?"

Comment: After the interrogative the verb is inverted. "What would you have done if it hit my eye?" is correct.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Neither is grammatically accurate in the situation you describe.  Something was done (a ball was struck or an object thrown?), which nearly hit the speaker in the eye.  The near victim remonstrates in the form of an unfulfilled (remote) conditional.

Conditionals follow clear rules of sequence.  Let’s re-organise to the more familiar *protasis / apodosis*.  The situation is that something that might have happened in the past **didn’t**.  So a past subjunctive is needed - which in English takes the same form as the pluperfect.

> If it **had** hit my eye, what would you have done.

So it should be

> What would you have done if it **had** hit my eye?